# Differences in raw text between downloaded PDF and the same PDF embedded in XML

Tags: pdf, notepad++, adobe-acrobat, xml

I am looking at publicly-available company filings on the SEC's EDGAR database. For each filing, there is a .txt file containing detailed information about the filing in what looks like XML format (I'm a beginner). Sometimes this is immediately useful text, but in a few cases, the information is a PDF file that appears to be embedded in a raw format that looks like ASCII. For example,

```
<PDF>
begin 644 filename1.pdf
M)5!$1BTQ+C4-)>+CS],-"C(X(#`@;V)J#3P\+TQI;F5A<FEZ960@,2],(#0T
M-34Y+T\@,S`O12`R-S@T,B].(#0O5"`T-#,P,B]((%L@-#0Q(#(P.%T^/@UE
M;F1O8FH-("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@#0HS."`P(&]B:@T\/"],96YG=&@@
M-C,O4F]O="`R.2`P(%(O241;/$1#0S%%,T$W,S9%0S8V-#`R-C-$.3DS1C(R
...
[...lots of text like this...]
...
)#0HE)45/1@T*
`
end
</PDF>
```

The fact that it's raw isn't surprising. What's surprising to me as a novice is that (1) if I try to copy/paste that raw text into Notepad++ and save as .pdf, Acrobat can't read the file, and (2) when I download (using Chrome) the actual .pdf from the filing, which is available elsewhere on the EDGAR system, and open it up in Notepad++, the raw text looks *much* different from the XML-file raw text, even though I expect them to encode the same file. For example,

```
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
28 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 44559/O 30/E 27842/N 4/T 44302/H [ 441 208]>>
endobj

38 0 obj
<</Length 63/Root 29 0 R/ID[<DCC1E3A736EC6640263D993F227A4DC8><71A0C1AA5F566D44A5466B14A0F219D4>]/Info 27 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/W[1 2 1]/Index[28 23]/DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Size 51/Prev 44303/Type/XRef>>stream
xÚbbd``b`ª@‚±  H0{    ¶‡@‚»Ä
Ö§a¬Ÿ˜Vƒt00’Fügœõ
 À =¸   ê
endstream
endobj
...
```

The files I'm talking about can be found here:
[The .txt file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/16732/0000000000-11-000286.txt)
[The .pdf file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/16732/000000000011000286/filename1.pdf)

**Why can't Acrobat read the raw text from the XML .txt file? Is there a way to alter that easily so it's readable?** Why does the raw text look so different when I download the actual PDF? Are they different representations of the same file, or is the published .pdf actually a much different file from what could be extracted from the .txt file?

I tried searching for information on ASCII and different types of Unicode, and found [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), but didn't see how to apply it to PDF files. I tried searching for how to extract PDF files embedded in XML, but did not find an answer that helped. I tried converting among encoding types in Notepad++, which was not fruitful.

Comment: This would be an answer if the question hadn't been closed already: the "text-like" PDF you showed is really a uuencoded version.  When you download it from the PDF-link using Chrome, it's downloading the actual binary PDF, not the uuencoded version.
If you saved the text-like version in Notepad++ as `some.pdf.uu`, then ran a [`uudecode`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sharutils.htm) on `some.pdf.uu`, it would extract the PDF in something Acrobat could read.

Comment: The above comment answered my question. I can't accept an answer because the question is closed, and I can't upvote the comment due to insufficient reputation.